# Overlapping R ggplots with two different y axis (different time period) and x axis (different scale)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have two different data sets, with two columns each (date and value). Basically, these two data sets differ in that they occur in different time periods (y axis), I would say roughly twenty years apart and as for the x axis (value) the ratio is about 1:10. The aim here is that since they occur in different time periods, is there a way for me to overlay these two plots using ggplot and have the two different y axes (different time periods) placed one above and the other below i.e. to say one of the dataset is from 1994-2002 and second dataset is 2017-2020. Reason is because they both exhibit the same pattern and i would like them to be placed together to exhibit the pattern clearly.
Example of such a chart is as attached.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some data and attempts?

Answer (score 0):

It's very doable. For ggplot2, you can easily add a secondary axis, with a simple transform. I'll use the EuStockMarkets data as an example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

rm(list=ls())
data(EuStockMarkets)
StockMarkets <- EuStockMarkets[, c("DAX","FTSE")]

plot(StockMarkets, plot.type="single", col=c(2,3), 
     main="European Stock Markets (1991 - 1998)", 
     ylab="Closing price (value)")
legend("topleft", inset=0.02,  legend=colnames(StockMarkets), 
         lwd=2, lty=1, col=c(2,3))
```

You'll get a nice plot like this:

[image: Euro Stock Market]

The ggplot2 version is also quite simple:

```
StockMarkets %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(sDate=as.Date(seq(1,1860,1), origin="1991-05-10")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-sDate) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=sDate, y=value, color=name)) +
  geom_line()
```

Now suppose FTSE is 20 years ago. I will change the date manually, so you can see the results.

```
DAX <- tibble(Stock=as.vector(EuStockMarkets[,c("DAX")])) %>%
   mutate(stDate=as.Date(seq(1,1860,1), origin="1991-05-10"), name="DAX")

FTSE <- tibble(Stock=as.vector(EuStockMarkets[,c("FTSE")])) %>%
  mutate(stDate=as.Date(seq(1,1860,1), origin="1971-05-10"), name="FTSE")
```

Now combine them into one data frame. Imagine you start with this data. And imagine it has NASDAQ and Bitcoin instead of FTSE and DAX.

```
DAX_FTSE <- bind_rows(DAX, FTSE)
```

If you try to plot this data, you get the following, which is correct, but not what the OP wanted:

```
DAX_FTSE %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=stDate, y=Stock, color=name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

The trick here is to add a secondary axis with a simple transform:

```
DAX_FTSE %>%
  mutate(st2Date=if_else(name=="FTSE", stDate+20*365.25, stDate)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=st2Date, y=Stock, color=name)) +
  geom_line() + xlab(label="DAX") +
  scale_x_date("DAX", sec.axis=sec_axis(~ . -20*365.25, name="FTSE"))
```

[image]